# intellij from existing sources wont run

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a couple of class files which i have previously developped with text editor, but want now to use intellij. Ive made a new project from sources. When i click run, i get the error at the bottom, and the run configs open up.

I am working on a simple swing app which i would like to build into a jar when im done.

Insights? i have already poked around to find a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a java source code using IntelliJ you should configure an application (like it was proposed) ...

So in the popup you've got, you have just to do the following :

- in the "Main Class" : select the java main class that you want to run (that have the method public static void main)
- you dont need to fill the VM options and the program arguments (if
  you do not need them)
- In the classpath module : select the Main Module (the project that
  contains the Main java class)

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention your main class in the 'Main Class' text filed in the 'Edit config'